# Filling corners in java using BorderLayout

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a window with buttons in the CENTER of a border layout and on the sides but the buttons on the NORTH side of the layout go through the buttons of the EAST and I only want them over the CENTER. Is there anyway to fill the top right corner with blanks or to stop generating buttons after reaching the end of the CENTER layout?

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Start {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame okno = new JFrame("igrica");
        okno.setVisible(true);
        okno.setSize(680,680);
        okno.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton[][] gumbi = new JButton[9][9];
        JButton[][] gumbi2 = new JButton [9][9];
        JButton[][] gumbi3 = new JButton [9][9];
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        okno.add(panel);

        JPanel igralnoPolje = new JPanel(new GridLayout(9, 9));
        panel.add(igralnoPolje, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
                gumbi[i][j] = new JButton();
                gumbi[i][j].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                gumbi[i][j].addActionListener(new Poslusalec(gumbi));
                igralnoPolje.add(gumbi[i][j]);

            }
        }


    //  BoxLayout vodoravneStevilke = new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS);


        JPanel vodoravneStevilke = new JPanel(new GridLayout(9, 9));
        panel.add(vodoravneStevilke, BorderLayout.EAST);

        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                gumbi2[i][j] = new JButton();
                gumbi2[i][j].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                gumbi2[i][j].setText("2");
        //      gumbi2[i][j].addActionListener(new Poslusalec(gumbi2));
                vodoravneStevilke.add(gumbi2[i][j]);

            }
        }

        JPanel navpicneStevilke = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 9));
        panel.add(navpicneStevilke, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                gumbi3[i][j] = new JButton();
                gumbi3[i][j].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                //gumbi3[i][j].addActionListener(new Poslusalec(gumbi));
                gumbi3[i][j].setText("2");

                navpicneStevilke.add(gumbi3[i][j]);
            }
        }   

    }
}
```

I'm a begginer in coding so i would apreaciate all the help possible
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there anyway to fill the top right corner with blanks or to stop generating buttons after reaching the end of the CENTER layout?

No. That is NOT the way a BorderLayout works.

See the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

You will need to use a more complex layout manager. I would guess you can use a `GridBagLayout`. Read the tutorial as you will need to play with the various constraints to achieve the desired layout.

Comment: what about insted of buttons if i just wanted some random numbers. would it be possible to align the numbers with the buttons below?

Comment: @minus, anything is possible with the right combination of layout managers. Sometimes you might need to nest panels with different layouts to get the desired result. Read the tutorial and experiment.